# A question about integer triples

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, integer-sequences

How can we generate all integer solutions of the equation

$$(qr+rp+pq)(x^2+y^2+z^2) = (p^2+q^2+r^2)(yz+zx+xy),$$

given that $p,q,r$ are integers?

Clearly if any one of $(x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,z,x), (y,x,z), (z,x,y), (z,y,x)$, is a solution, so are the others, so let's assume $x \leq y \leq z$. Also assume that $x,y,z$ are relatively prime, since then $(kx,ky,kz)$ is a solution for every integer $k$.

Example: if $(p,q,r) = (0,1,2)$, the solutions include $(2,4,15), (3,14,40), (4,30,77), (5,6,28), (5,52,126)$.

Comment: So there are "obvious" solutions when both $xy+yz+zx=pq+qr+rs=0$ or $x+y+z=p+q+r=0$ . Otherwise note that you can rewrite the above as being $\sum (\frac{x}{x+y+z})^2=\sum (\frac{p}{p+q+r})^2$. Now you can think about this as looking for rational points on the intersection of the sphere $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ with $a+b+c=1$.

Comment: To finish off you can write these solutions in parametric form. Namely note that this intersection is an ellipse so it should have a nice form. To do it substitute $c=1-a-b$. This give $a^2+b^2+ab-a-b=0$ and the equation of the underlying ellipse is $3X^2+Y^2=4$ where $X=2a+b-1$ and $Y=3b-1$.

Comment: To parametrize the ellipse note that you have the obvious rational point $(0,2)$ and any other rational point on the ellipse will determine a line with this rational point of rational slope. Thus we can write all the solutions as $X=t(Y-2)$ for $t\in\mathbb{Q}$. This gives $Y=\cfrac{6t^2-2}{3t^2+1}$ and $X=\cfrac{4t}{3t^2+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$(qr+rp+pq)(x^2+y^2+z^2)=(p^2+q^2+r^2)(yz+zx+xy)$

$m,n,p,q,r$ are arbitrary.
Substitute $ x=t+p, y=mt+q, z=nt+r$ to above equation,
then we get $$\scriptsize{t = \frac{(r^2q+2qrp-p^3-q^3-q^2p+r^2p-p^2q)n+(-rp^2+2qrp-r^3-p^3+q^2p+q^2r-r^2p)m+rp^2+p^2q-r^2q-q^2r-r^3-q^3+2qrp}{(-qr-pq-rp)n^2+((q^2+p^2+r^2)m+q^2+p^2+r^2)n+(-qr-pq-rp)m^2+(q^2+p^2+r^2)m-qr-pq-rp}.}$$
Thus, we get a parametric solution below.

$x = (p^2q+qrp+rp^2)m^2+((-r^2p-p^3-pq^2)n+r^3-q^2r-2qrp-2pq^2+rp^2)m+(p^2q+qrp+rp^2)n^2+(q^3-r^2q-2qrp-2r^2p+p^2q)n-qrp+r^2q+q^2r+q^3+r^3.$

$y = (r^2p+p^3+r^3-qrp+rp^2)m^2+((-r^2p-2qrp+pq^2+p^3-2r^2q)n-2qrp-rp^2+q^2r-2p^2q+r^3)m+(pq^2+q^2r+qrp)n^2+(-r^2q-q^3-p^2q)n+pq^2+q^2r+qrp.$

$z = (r^2p+r^2q+qrp)m^2+((-pq^2+r^2p+p^3-2qrp-2q^2r)n-rp^2-r^3-q^2r)m+(pq^2+p^3+q^3-qrp+p^2q)n^2+(q^3-p^2q-2rp^2-2qrp+r^2q)n+r^2p+r^2q+qrp.$

Example for $(p,q,r)=(0,1,2).$
$(x,y,z)>1, gcd(x,y,z)=1$
$$\frac{(q^2+r^2+p^2)}{(qr+pq+rp)}=\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{(yz+zx+xy)}=5/2. $$ 
 $[ m,   n ,  x ,     y,     z ]=[ 0,   0,   15,    2,    4], [ 0,   3,    6,    5,   28],[ 0,   4,    3,   14,   40],[ 1,   2,   15,    2,    4],[ 1,   5,    6,    5,   28],[ 2,   4,   15,    2,        4],[ 3,   0,   33,  104,   10],[ 3,   1,   30,   77,    4],[ 4,   0,   39,  170,   28],[ 4,   2,   33,  104,   10],[ 4,   3,   30,   77,    4],[ 5,   1,   42,  209,   40],[ 5,   2,   39,  170,   28],[ 5,   4,   33,  104,   10],[ 5,   5,   30,   77,    4].$

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate finding all **primitive integer** solutions, let us take $(p,q,r) = (106,92,1)$ In this case, all $x,y,z$ will be positive, and we may simply put them in decreasing order. There are three distinct parametrizations, each component a quadratic form in (coprime) integer variables $u,v,$ just like Pythagorean Triples...

$$ 106 u^2 + 197 uv + 92 v^2 \; , \; \;  92 u^2 -13 uv +  v^2 \; , \; \;   u^2 + 15 uv + 106 v^2 \; .  $$

$$ 124 u^2 + 179 uv + 65 v^2 \; , \; \;  65 u^2 -49 uv + 10  v^2 \; , \; \;  10 u^2 + 69 uv + 124 v^2 \; .  $$

$$ 130 u^2 + 159 uv + 49 v^2 \; , \; \;  49 u^2 -61 uv + 20  v^2 \; , \; \;  20 u^2 + 101 uv + 130 v^2 \; .  $$

Take a pair $(u,v)$ and produce the triples given by each recipe above. If any triple comes out nonprimitive (some gcd > 1) just discard that. The primitive version will be constructed by one of the other recipes. Oh, and put in decreasing order. Call that triple $(x,y,z).$ Below, the triple in brackets is the first quadratic form in that recipe, such as <106,197,92>.

```
    x          y         z       first quad. form     u  v
   106        92         1      < 106, 197, 92 >      1  0    
   124        65        10      < 124, 179, 65 >      1  0    
   130        49        20      < 130, 159, 49 >      1  0    
   338       251         8      < 130, 159, 49 >      1  1    
   368       203        26      < 124, 179, 65 >      1  1    
   395       122        80      < 106, 197, 92 >      1  1    
   887       412        94      < 130, 159, 49 >      2  1    
   919       302       172      < 124, 179, 65 >      2  1    
  1333      1246         8      < 124, 179, 65 >      1  3    
  1493      1048        46      < 130, 159, 49 >      1  3    
  1525      1000        62      < 106, 197, 92 >      1  3    
  1637       790       160      < 106, 197, 92 >      3  1    
  1696       613       278      < 130, 159, 49 >      3  1    
  1718       448       421      < 124, 179, 65 >      3  1    
  1915      1856        10      < 130, 159, 49 >      2  3    
  2155      1570        56      < 124, 179, 65 >      2  3    
  2270      1880        29      < 124, 179, 65 >      1  4    
  2320      1306       155      < 130, 159, 49 >      3  2    
  2434      1048       299      < 106, 197, 92 >      2  3    
  2450      1000       331      < 124, 179, 65 >      3  2    
  2504      1550       125      < 130, 159, 49 >      1  4    
  2504       754       523      < 106, 197, 92 >      3  2
```

Comment: for additional information on this approach, including what "ratios" $\frac{yz+zx+xy}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ are possible, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225781/fricke-klein-method-for-isotropic-ternary-quadratic-forms

Comment: If the "ratio" is below one half, there are integer triples with some positive and some negative entries. When the ratio is above one half, such as the $50/99$ I display in my answer, all $x,y,z$ will be positive.