# Computing the genus of certain ternary indefinite lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms

For $k$ a positive integer, let us consider the rank 3 ternary indefinite lattice $L=L_k$ with quadratic form
$$6kx^2-2(y^2+yz+z^2).$$
Its discriminant group has length $2$.

> **Question.** Is this lattice unique in its genus?

Theorem 21 Chapter 15 of the book "Sphere packing, Lattices and Groups" by Conway and Sloane states that, in order to be not unique, one should have that $4\cdot 18k$ is divisible by $t^3$ for some non-square natural number $t=0$ or $1\, \operatorname{mod}\, 4$. But I would like a general result and to know exactly what is going on for any $k$.

Perhaps it is too much asking; to see one example of $k$ such that the lattice $L_k$ is not unique in its genus would also be interesting.

Comment: why these particular forms?

Comment: oh, well. From Watson's little book, the forms $x^2 +xy-y^2 +25 z^2$ and $5x^2+ 5xy-5y^2 + z^2$  are in the same genus but are distinct. Page 116.

Comment: same for the positive forms $x^2 + xy + y^2 + 9 z^2$  and $x^2 + 3 y^2 + 3yz + 3z^2,$ same genus, each alone in its spinor genus  so both are regular in the sense of Dickson. http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Mathematika_1997.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy I am interested by these forms because they have an order 3 automorphism preserving them. Thank you very much for the examples ; do you know examples that are indefinite ?

Comment: the example with 5 and 25 is indefinite forms. Your (indefinite) pattern does not seem to be cooperating as far as producing more than one class in a genus.

Comment: infinitely many examples in example 1.2 in https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/schulze/Preprints/feixu_rsp_spinorgenera.pdf  for instance $4x^2 +25 y^2 - 5 z^2$

Comment: @WillJagy: thank you so much for the example and the reference!

Comment: @WillJagy In your example, $4x^2+25y^2-5z^2=1$ has no solution, since $n=5$  is not congruent to $1,3,7 mod 8$. Reading the introduction of the paper, I may suppose that locally there is a solution (?), but the Hasse principle do not apply, thus this implies that the genus has two elements at least. I see that kind of result in Corollary 1 p.4 of that paper: http://www.wordpress.jonhanke.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ternary-QF-Survey.pdf however this is rather vague and there is no reference. Do you know such references ? Thank you very much

Comment: It becomes easier when the ternary is a unary plus a binary. $x^2 + 100 y^2$  and $4x^2 + 25 y^2$ are in the same genus; the other genus is the pair $8x^2 \pm 4xy +13 y^2$ Furthermore, $4x^2 + 25 y^2$ is a square but not a fourth power in the class group, therefore in a different spinor genus from the identity. http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Estes_Pall_1973.pdf    and, really, everything else I put at  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Comment: @WillJagy : thank you so much! I will study these references

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in
Rick Miranda and David R. Morrison, Embeddings of Integral QuadraticForms
[https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~drm/manuscripts/eiqf.pdf](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Edrm/manuscripts/eiqf.pdf)
Chapter VIII Theorem 7.5 (2) and the following Lemmas

Namely, for any $k$ the quadratic form is

- 2-regular (Lemma 7.7 (1))
- 3-semiregular (Lemma 7.6 (2))
- p-regular for
  all $p\neq 2,3$ (Lemma 7.6 (1))

If you have a finite number of examples in mind you can use sage. I implemented spinor genera for the recent version of sageMath following Conway Sloane's description in SPLAG.

```
for k in range(1,100): 
    D = matrix(ZZ,3,3,[2,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,-3*2*k]) 
    rep = Genus(D).representatives() 
    len(rep)
```

Comment: Thank you much Simon! I will study that paper!