# Generators of the automorphism group of a quadratic form

Tags: quadratic-forms, 4-manifolds, orthogonal-groups

Suppose that $q$ is an integral quadratic form, not necessarily unimodular or even non-degenerate, and write $O_q(\mathbb{Z})$ for its automorphism group. According to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76352/orthogonal-group-of-quadratic-form) this group is finitely generated, but I gather that writing down a list of generators isn't so easy.

Suppose that $q$ is strongly indefinite, in the sense that its rank is large compared to its signature. Are generators known in this case?  More precisely, let $q_n$ be the orthogonal direct sum of $q$ with $n$ copies of the hyperbolic form $H$ of rank $2$. Are generators (not necessarily a finite list) of $O_{q_n}(\mathbb{Z})$ known?

In the case of unimodular forms, generators are known by the work of Wall (On the orthogonal groups of unimodular quadratic
forms. II. Journal für die reine und angewandte
Mathematik **213** (1963/4), 122 - 136.) The simple form of these generators makes them very useful for applications to $4$-manifolds, which is my motivation for this question.  If the assumption that $q$ is non-degenerate simplifies matters, I'd be interested in the answer to the question in that situation.